# puppetter jest setup: why __BROWSER_GLOBAL__ isn't accessible in test?

Tags: node.js, jestjs, puppeteer

Reading from https://jestjs.io/docs/en/puppeteer

I came across this code, `__BROWSER_GLOBAL__` is defined in setup.js

```
//setup.js
global.__BROWSER_GLOBAL__ = browser;
```

and for testing purpose, the example defines `__BROWSER__` in puppetter_environment.js

```
//puppetter_environment.js
global.__BROWSER__ = await puppeteer.connect({
  browserWSEndpoint: wsEndpoint,
});
```

in tests, it uses the `__BROWSER__` for accessing puppetter. when I tried to console log the `__BROWSER_GLOBAL__` it returns undefined.

but in teardown.js `__BROWSER_GLOBAL__` seems accessible

```
//teardown.js
await global.__BROWSER_GLOBAL__.close();
```

why `__BROWSER_GLOBAL__` accessible in teardown.js and not in tests?

and why can't I assign another attribute in setup.js? it will be undefined, same as the `__BROWSER_GLOBAL__`